# How to setup a Domain Controller in the cloud

Tags: active-directory, amazon-ec2, vpn, domain-controller, windows-server-2012-r2

We are implementing a new Windows Server 2012 R2 domain controller for our 2 small offices, and we want to set it up on Amazon EC2. I have read that with this type of setup you normally use a VPN. How would this be setup connection wise without forcing all traffic through the domain controller? We don't want all traffic to have to travel through the domain controller first, we only want to connect to the controller for authentication. We are using pfsense enterprise routers.

Answer (score 8):

> How would this be setup connection wise without forcing all traffic through the domain controller?

With site to site VPNs.  You'd set up your cloud assets as a site, and then establish a site-to-site VPN between your cloud site and each of your physical sites.

An alternate option, that Microsoft uses, but is generally ill-advised (unless you really, *really* know what you're doing) is exposing the domain controller to the internet, and securing access with IPSec. (Don't do this: site-to-site VPNs are much safer.)

Comment: So not all traffic would travel to the remote cloud-based domain controller? For some reason I was under the impression that all traffic would hit the cloud server first and then anywhere else it was destined.

Comment: @pmilb I suppose you could route your traffic to traverse the site-to-site VPNs for everything, but that would be pretty dumb, and it certainly not setup that way by default... so safe to say your impression is mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

We have lot of possibilities to create or extend a DC to cloud.
firstly, we have EC2 services to host a new AD or extend your AD to cloud.
Please refer to the AWS directory services.

[AWS Directory Service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/adminguide/what_is.html)

Now you could also launch a windows server with AD service configured over a VPN connection(you can use direct connect or linux server VPN) to the Datacenter where your DC resides and your AWS VPC. 
Set up the DHCP options pointing to the DC where you want the logins to authenticate.